# Сколько потоков использует BeginGetResponse?

Tags: c#, асинхронность, сокет

Подскажите пожалуйста, асинхронная операция BeginGetResponse действительно асинхронная и не использует потоки или все таки создается какой то пул потоков при большом количестве запросов? В плане производительности (например для получения html страниц) что лучше использовать - запросы на асинхронных сокетах или просто асинхронные запросы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IAsyncResult` на то и асинхронный, чтобы выполняться в отдельном потоке. Вообще говоря, предположить себе асинхронность без деления на потоки в контексте задачи просто невозможно *(готов допустить, что есть теоретические случаи, вроде хитрой асинхронности на сигналах или мессаджах, но к задаче это не относится)*. Подробнее про использование `ThreadPool` при работе с `IAsyncResult` можно прочитать [**здесь.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)

По второй части вопроса - естественно, нужен бенчмарк, однако можно предположить, что с версии `.NET 3.5` имеет смысл пользоваться асинхронными сокетами. Начиная с 3.5, библиотека для работы с сокетами была оптимизирована, и теперь она поддерживает до 60000 одновременно открытых сокетов, чего, в принципе, должно хватать для достаточно большого спектра задач. Опираясь на эту информацию, можно предположить, что **имеет смысл сгрузить вопросы производительности асинхронных запросов на `CLR` и забыть об этом.**

*Более подробно - [**здесь**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163356.aspx) и [**здесь**.](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Csharp/36140546/asynchronous-socket-programing-and-thread-pool.aspx)*